# WAMP easy setup installer?

Tags: installation, lamp

Is there any way to make an installer that is very user friendly?

I know it's impossible for a Next Next Finished installer but what can I do to ease the process?

Windows platform.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a very simple application and basically just need to copy a few files, I'd suggest looking at [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net/). It's very simple and you can probably have an installer done in a couple of days.

If you're developing software for a corporate environment where network rollouts are a priority, then you'll probably want to take a closer look at [Windows Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=6A35AC14-2626-4846-BB51-DDCE49D6FFB6) and [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](http://wix.sf.net/). (Warning: a very *steep* learning curve - you'll want to set aside a few weeks and probably read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592972) to help get started)

If you want the benefits of MSI, without the hassle of learning the underlying technology then a commercial tool such as [Installshield](http://www.installshield.com/) is your best bet. It's not cheap but you'll get something out the door pretty quickly.

Long term I'd advise learning Windows Installer technology. It's something overlooked by most developers, it's often seen as crazy voodoo that is overly complicated and unnecessary, in reality it's rather quite simple, just a database with a whole bunch of rules, conditions, and quirks that take a bit of getting used to :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [BitNami WAMPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack) it is open source and free (you also have Linux and OS X versions)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I'm not sure how you didn't find this already...

http://www.wampserver.com/en/